# Query string in htaccess rule doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, query-string

I've a problem with the rule below:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^[ROOT]/([0-9]+)_(.*)$ https://www.[DOMAIN].[EXT]/[ROOT]/$1-$2?page=([0-9]+) [R=301,L]
```

I need to redirect the old qs parameter (p) to the new one (page), but the result is this:

https://www.[DOMAIN].[EXT]/[ROOT]/[ID]-[STRING]?page=([0-9]+)

I mean: if I've ?p=4 I need to go to ?page=4

I don't understand what's wrong

Thank you all

Comment: `([0-9]+)` in the *replacement* part doesn't make sense. You need a concrete *value* there, not a match expression.

Comment: Thanks for your answer deceze. So, I need to mange all single issue? if I've p=4 in the rule I need to write:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=4
RewriteRule ^[ROOT]/([0-9]+)_(.*)$ https://www.[DOMAIN].[EXT]/[ROOT]/$1-$2?page=4 [R=301,L]

and so on

Comment: No, you need to use the value matched in the `RewriteCond`: `%1` (analogous to `$1` and `$2` you're already using). Read the documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: You want to start reading the documentation of the rewriting module. It comes with really great examples: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html